# multiple matches in regex in hive

Tags: arrays, regex, hive, hiveql, ip-address

When I run

`select regexp_extract("hosts: 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 host",'((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)',0);`

I got     `192.168.1.1`.
But what i want is `192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2` or `["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"]`

What should I do, change reg or create a UDF?

Answer (score 0):

Split string, explode, check each part for regexp matching, collect array of matching parts, if necessary to get string from array, use concat_ws() to concatenate array:

```
with your_data as(
select stack(1, 'hosts: 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 host' ) as hosts
)

select collect_set(case when part rlike '((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)' 
                        then part 
                  else null end )
from your_data d
     lateral view explode(split(hosts, ' +')) s as part;
```

Result:

```
["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"]
```

Comment: @billsteve Please consider accepting the answer/voting if it really useful